# How to know if two sets of points have same pattern

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, similarity

I have 2 sets of points in 3D have the same count, I want to know if the have the same pattern, I thought I may project them on XZ,XY and YZ planes then compare the projections in each plane but I am not sure how to do this, I thought the convex hull may help but it won't be accurate.
Is there an easy algorithm to do that? the complexity is not a big issue so far as the points count will be tiny, I implement in Java.

Can I solve this in 3D direct with the same algorithm ?

The attached image shows an example of what I mean.

Edit:
No guarantee for order.
No scale, there are rotation and translation only.

[image]

Comment: If the points are numbered correspondingly, so that in your picture point 1 would be at the top of the left hand panel and at the bottom of the right hand panel and so on, this could be treated as a procrustes problem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrustes_analysis for example

Comment: Which types of translations are allowed? Can one be bigger than the other? Can one be a mirror of the other? Are indeed the points numbered in the same way, or is there no such guarantee?

Comment: @trincot they will be the same size, no scale only translation and rotation

Comment: So mirroring is not allowed? What about the other question (point order)?

Comment: @trincot no guarantee for order, may be the same or not

Comment: ........so mirroring is not allowed?

Comment: @trincot No it isn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would gather some information about each point: information that only depends on "shape", not on the actual translation/rotation. For instance, it could be the sum of all the distances between the point and any other point of the shape. Or it could be the largest angle between any two points, as seen from the point under consideration. Choose whatever metric brings the most diversity.

Then sort the points by that metric.

Do the above for both groups of points.

As a first step you can compare both groups by their sorted list of metrics. Allow for a little error margin, since you will be dealing with floating point precision limitations. If they cannot be mapped to each other, abort the algorithm: they are different shapes.

Now translate the point set so that the first point in the ordered list is mapped to the origin (0, 0, 0), i.e. subtract the first point from all points in the group.

Now rotate the point set around the Y axis, so that the second point in the ordered list coincides with XY plane. The rotate the point set around the Z axis, so that that point coincides with the X-axis: it should map to (d, 0, 0), where *d* is the distance between the first and second point in the sorted list.

Finally, rotate the point set around the X axis, so that the third point in the ordered list coincides with the XY plane. If that point is colinear with the previous points, you need to continue doing this with the next point(s) until you have rotated a non-colinear point.

Do this with both groups of points. Then compare the so-transformed coordinates of both lists.

This is the main algorithm, but I have omitted the cases where the metric value is the same for two points, and thus the sorted list could have permutations without breaking the sort order:

In that case you need to perform the above transformations with the different permutations of those equally valued points at the start of the sorted list, for as long as there is no fit.

Also, while checking the fit, you should take into account that the matching point may not be in the exact same order as in the other group's sorted list, and you should verify the next points that have the same metric as well.

Comment: The "sorting by metric" approach is interesting. If the coordinates are noisy, the permutations of close values should also be tried.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a fixed object with different shapes and movements, pair-wise- or multi-matching can be a helpful solution for you. For example see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.10541.pdf). This method can be extended for higher-dimensions as well.

> [image]

If you have two different sets of points that come from different objects and you find the similarity between them, one solution can be computing [discrete Frechet distance](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.937&rep=rep1&type=pdf) in both sets of points and then compare their value.

> [image]

The other related concept is **Shape Reconstruction**. You can mix the result of a proper shape reconstruction algorithm with two previous methods to compute the similarity:

> [image]

Comment: I think it is complex, may be there are easier algorithm ?

Comment: @MohamedMoussa Hence, you should be more specific. Please elaborate on your problem and update your post.

Comment: I just need to know if the two sets has the same patter / shape or not